# Converting an epoch timesramp to a formatted date string in php

Tags: php, epoch

I am attempting to convert an epoch timestamp value to a formatted date string in PHP and getting unexpected results:

```
$dateStart = 1104555600000;
$formattedDate = date('Y-m-d', $dateStart);

Expected Result: 2005-01-01   
Actual Result: 1993-09-26
```

`1104555600000` is equivalent to `2005-01-01`

However, `$formattedDate` ends up being `1993-09-26`

Comment: Whats the source of the epoch? `1104555600000` looks like too many zeros. `echo strtotime( '2005-01-01' );` produces `1104566400` on my system.

Comment: Your epoch is in miliseconds. Try seconds.

Comment: What @JosephSzymborski said, try removing the three trailing digits or divide it by 1,000.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you mean divide it with 1000

Comment: @am05mhz tomaytoe tomahtoe... This isn't English class.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that comment was before you edit your comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you epoch timestamp is in millisecond, convert it to second and then convert it to date

```
<?php

$dateStart = 1104555600000;
echo $formattedDate = date('Y-m-d', $dateStart/1000);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/981417

Comment: how come the divided by 1000 is not working when passing an epoch timestamp such as: 4307486400000 which should be year 2160? Instead it is converting to year 1970.